Test and Coverage not reflecting in Summary tab in Azure DevOps for frontend applications(ReactJs)
Test and Coverage not reflecting in Summary (test and coverage) tab in Azure DevOps for frontend applications. As the result is visible under the Code Coverage tab. It is reflecting for backend applications but not reflecting for frontend (NodeJS/Angular/React) applications.
For getting code coverage we are using Publish code coverage results v2 task in our pipelines. Please suggest the solution

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
